# What is the motivation for legally forcing sellers to determine the minimum price of food by multiplying it by 1.1?

Tags: france, food

A radio advertisement for a food distributor said that they sell their food to fight the current crisis at "prix coutant" (cost price). However, it was followed by a very speedy text saying that, according to the law, the actual cost price was actually 1.1 times the real cost price.

This seems confirmed by this [governmental source](https://www.economie.gouv.fr/dgccrf/Publications/Vie-pratique/Fiches-pratiques/revente-a-perte), saying:

> À compter du 1er février 2019 et jusqu’au 15 avril 2023, le prix
> d’achat effectif est affecté d’un coefficient de 1,10 pour les denrées
> alimentaires et les produits destinés à l’alimentation des animaux.

> From February 1 2019 until April 15 2023, the effective purchase price is multiplied by a coefficient of 1.10 for foodstuffs and animal feed.

I think I am misunderstanding something here, but what I understand is:

- I am a food seller, I buy some food at 1€
- I want to make an advertisement and want to sell the food at cost price
- I cannot do so; I am actually forced by law to sell it at 1.1€ (so I am still making a profit)

Is that correct? What is the motivation behind this?

Comment: The "current" crisis? What crisis do they refer to? Feb 2019 predates both Corona and the Ukrainean war.

Comment: @JonathanReez - why :-) instead of :-( ?

Comment: @PMF If I'm understanding correctly, it's the advertising that is referring to a "current crisis", the law (from 2019) does not.

Comment: The advertising was from a private company and they did not explain what they meant by that (price going up I guess ?)

Comment: @PMF The crisis that was taking place in france at that time was the giant gilets jaunes protests - I suspect this might have lead to temporary measures around price fixing and stock dumping, but I'm not totally sure.

Comment: The law has been in effect since 1986 (https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/loda/id/LEGIARTI000006527750/1986-12-09/#LEGIARTI000006527750). What changes from time to time is the minimum profit (used to be 0, is 1.1 these days - for food)

Comment: @Maxime No, the change in cost is from 1.0 to 1.1, the change in profit is from 0 (no profit) to 0.1 (10%).

Comment: The traditional motivation for setting the price of anything as a factor - here, not minimum nor maximum but a flat 1.1 - of cost is the 'cost-plus' principle: in a controlled market, the regulator dictates that, eg 1.1, is the reasonable margin.

Did you notice how the first, presumably crucial paragraph of that exposition contradicts both itself and the wording of the Question?

'… the actual cost price was actually 1.1 times the real cost price…' is a mistake, though perhaps only of typing or translation.

Comment: Is your question about why they can't sell at less than 1 €, or why they can't sell at less than 1.10 € (i.e. why 10% is added)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On one hand, the law does defines "prix d'achat effectif" (effective purchase price), which is the cost on the invoice, minus any sort discount obtained outside, plus various taxes and costs. In spirit, it's the price at which the seller would break even all things considered, though obviously the reality might vary on a case by case basis.

[Code de commerce, Article L442-5](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/article_lc/LEGIARTI000038414250):

> Le prix d'achat effectif est le prix unitaire net figurant sur la facture d'achat, minoré du montant de l'ensemble des autres avantages financiers consentis par le vendeur exprimé en pourcentage du prix unitaire net du produit et majoré des taxes sur le chiffre d'affaires, des taxes spécifiques afférentes à cette revente et du prix du transport.

It should be noted that it forbids not only the sale below that price, but also explicitly forbids the advertisement of such sale:

> Le fait, pour tout commerçant, de revendre ou d'annoncer la revente d'un produit en l'état à un prix inférieur à son prix d'achat effectif

The motivation behind this is that it's an anti-dumping and consumer protection measure. Larger companies could afford to sell stuff at a loss and drive smaller companies out of business, creating a monopoly where they could then raise prices at will, at the consumer's expense. More generally, French and European law aims to forbid unfair competition, monopolies, and other cartels.

The law 2020-1525 "Accélération et simplification de l'action publique" adds to the effective purchase price definition, which is where the extra 10% comes in, minus some costs and taxes still.

[Loi n° 2020-1525, Article 125](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/loda/article_lc/LEGIARTI000042624464/):

> le prix d'achat effectif défini au deuxième alinéa du I de l'article L. 442-5 du code de commerce est majoré d'un montant égal au produit d'un coefficient 0,1 par une valeur P, égale au prix d'achat effectif défini au même deuxième alinéa minoré du montant des droits de consommation mentionnés au I de l'article 403 du code général des impôts et du montant des cotisations prévues à l'article L. 245-7 du code de la sécurité sociale.

This is defined under title IV of the law, called "Diverses dispositions de simplification", but I can't really tell if this was the simplification of an existing rule (as the name of the title would suggest) or not.

Regarding your question, the general idea is that your minimum resale price is buying price +10%-ish, but the 1€ and 1.1€ figures would be modified by a variety of costs, discounts, and other taxes.

---

On the other hand, "prix coutant" doesn't have a legal definition, or none that I could find at least. It clears the requirement that it wouldn't reasonably be understood as selling at a loss (doing or advertising so would be illegal anyways).

However it maintains an ambiguity on whether it means "the lowest price we can legally sell at", or "the lowest price we can afford to sell at", which may or may not be the same price. So it can be argued to be technically correct advertisement either way.

Answer (score 53):

The law against *revente à perte* (resale at a loss) is an anti-[dumping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dumping_(pricing_policy)) law intended to prevent [predatory pricing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predatory_pricing).

As explained in the Wikipedia article for the case of *[Keck and Mithouard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keck_and_Mithouard)*:

> The aim of this law was to prevent retailers engaging in 'cut-throat competition' by dumping excess produce onto the market, and forcing competitors out of business.

Comment: Interesting related video on how the price of beans was negative in the UK at one point https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JGI4RAKdNLs

Comment: ScottishTapWater, Save time, start at 3:00.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica then it's https://youtu.be/JGI4RAKdNLs?t=180

Comment: Selling at 1.09 would not be "at a loss", and yet it's prohibited. Why?

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh in terms of dumping & monopoly, whether it's a lethal loss or not is a matter of other costs too of course (rent, employees etc..) so perhaps the 10% is to protect smaller sellers/retailers who buy such commodities in lower volume and likely at different (higher) prices than a dumping giant.

Comment: I'd of course note that the necessity and effectiveness of anti-dumping regulation is highly questionable. A true free market probably doesn't need such regulation.

Comment: @JonathanReez a true free market has no protection against predatory pricing, cartels, and things like that. In a true free market you're free to price your smaller competitors out of existence and then inflate prices indefinitely to maximise profit over the backs of customers, even if 90% of them can no longer afford to feed themselves.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh no doubt a percentage of expected spoilage is taken into the price point. If you have to throw away 10% of your produce because it's over date, selling at a 9% markup IS selling at a loss.

Comment: @jwenting this presupposes that once you price out your competitors, you're safe from competition forever. In practice dumping is a risky strategy because new competition appears every single day.

Comment: @JonathanReez And in practice, monopolies and near monopolies form all of the time.  "In a true free market" sounds a lot like the no true scottsman trick.  It is *observed* that using dumping and similar strategies successfully generates significant economic profits via monopoly power.  If your mathematical model says it doesn't happen in a "true free market", then all you have proven is your mathematical model does not apply to pretty much every actual real economies observed.

Comment: @Yakk there are no examples of persistent, consumer-harmful monopolies lasting for more than a few years in areas where market entry isn't restricted by the government (including restrictions on foreign competitors) or by organized crime.

Comment: @JonathanReez So no true scottsman!  Comcast has a monopoly on 47 million American broadband consumers?  Well, if the government touches anything in the entire area we can blame it!  Theory is IMPOSSIBLE TO REFUTE!  Your model is not useful, it does not have predictive value: please try again.

Comment: @Yakk I can recommend the book Basic Economics by Thomas Sowell. Would help you understand the faults in your reasoning.

Comment: @JonathanReez I can recommend reading non-basic economics texts sometimes.  It might help you with yours.  I'm aware of economic models; when they fail to model actual real world economic behavior, the solution isn't "well, no true scottsman".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143120/discussion-between-yakk-and-jonathanreez).

Answer (score 25):

This is actually not that unusual. In many places, a retailer will sell some products as a "loss leader" to get people in the store to then, hopefully, buy other products where they can make a profit. But that can be controversial at times, and some places have laws to prevent this. A big concern is that a large company might sell at a loss to pull customers away from the competition. Once the competition is out of business due to low sales (or due to losing money because they match the price), the large company has a monopoly and raises prices to make excess profit. An example of this is with gasoline pricing. The [Sheetz company had a special gas promotion but couldn't run it in certain states](https://foxbaltimore.com/news/local/sheetz-199-thanksgiving-sale-unleaded88-maryland-law-prevents-sale-west-virginia-gas-station-fuel-petroleum-drivers-gasoline) due to legal restrictions.

Answer (score 16):

Note that as the food seller in your example you do have additional costs on top of the 1€ for the food item. You need to pay your employees (or yourself) and presumably also need some space where the food item is stored and the sale to end customers takes place. These costs are the motivation for the extra 10%.

I have no idea whether 10% is a reasonable amount for a food seller but if you were to sell the items at the 1€ you paid yourself you certainly would lose money which the law is trying to prevent as an anti-dumping measure as explained in sjy's answer.